# Spark split and parse json in column

Tags: json, apache-spark, split, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe:

```
catalogid   | 1123798                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
catalogpath | [{"1123798":"Other, poets"},{"1112194":"   Poetry for kids"}
```

With schema:

```
StructType(List(StructField(catalogid,StringType,true),StructField(catalogpath,StringType,true)))
```

And I need get only text (values) from catalogpath column - something like this:

```
catalogid   | 1123798                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
catalog_desc| "Other, poets"; "Poetry for kids"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON parser:

```
import json
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, concat_ws


@udf("array<string>")
def parse(s):
    try:
        return list(chain.from_iterable(x.values() for x in json.loads(s)))
    except:
        pass

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1123798, """[{"1123798":"Other, poets"},{"1112194":"   Poetry for kids"}]""")],
    ("catalogid", "catalogpath")
)

result = df.select("catalogid", parse("catalogpath").alias("catalog_desc"))

result.show(truncate=False)
# +---------+----------------------------------+
# |catalogid|catalog_desc                      |
# +---------+----------------------------------+
# |1123798  |[Other, poets,    Poetry for kids]|
# +---------+----------------------------------+
```

If you want a single string you can apply `concat_ws`:

```
result.withColumn("catalog_desc", concat_ws(";", "catalog_desc")).show(truncate=False)
# +---------+-------------------------------+
# |catalogid|catalog_desc                   |
# +---------+-------------------------------+
# |1123798  |Other, poets;   Poetry for kids|
# +---------+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `udf` function with string functions should do the trick for you

```
import re
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
def parseString(str):
    return ";".join([re.sub("[}\{]", "", x[x.index(":")+1:]) for x in str.split("},{")])

parseUdf = f.udf(parseString, t.StringType())

df.withColumn('1123798', parseUdf(df['1123798'])).show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+-----------+----------------------------------+
|catalogid  |1123798                           |
+-----------+----------------------------------+
|catalogpath|"Other, poets";"  Poetry for kids"|
+-----------+----------------------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful